# Checking array for tags

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I call a service which returns an array of tags. The array may be empty, and if so, it just saves the tag. Otherwise, it checks if the tag is in the array. If so, then the tag is removed, otherwise it's saved.

Can this be optimized for efficiency?

```
function processTag(total, tag, associatedTicker) {
    var foundFlag = false;

    TagFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags').then(function(data) {
        console.log('onlyTags data',data);

        // Is there are selected Tags:
        if (data.length > 0) {
            // Search for tag in tagFactory
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].term_id === tag.term_id) {
                    foundFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If found, remove tag:
            if (foundFlag) {
                removeTag(tag, associatedTicker);
            }
            else {
                // Save the tag:
                if (total < 3) {
                    saveTag(tag, associatedTicker);
                }
                // 3 are already selected, display alert:
                else {
                    displayAlert('failure', 'Only 3 tags can be monitored at a time.');
                }
            }
        }
        // Else if there are no selected tags:
        else {
            saveTag(tag, associatedTicker);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do `removeTag` and `saveTag` iterate the array, too?

Comment: @LittleSanti no, it just takes the tag and either push it into the Array, the removeTag function does remove it from the Array, but it does it by removing the tag from an Object in another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rewrite that clarifies and shortens the code.  A few of its advantages:

- Removes nested if... else statements
- Replaces vague variable name `data` with something more descriptive.
- Names the concepts you are implicitly using in your code (eg, "checkedSave" means "check if it's valid to save the tag, then save it").  We also name the various conditions we are interested in: `noSavedTags` and `tagAlreadyExists`.
- Avoid unnecessary indendation by not defining our callback `saveOrRemoveTag` inline.
- Avoid verbose, unsightly `for` loop by using using `map` and `indexOf` to check if the tag already exists.
- User ternary operator instead of `if... else` to express simple conditional expressions.

The new code:

```
function processTag(total, tag, associatedTicker) {

    TagFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags').then(saveOrRemoveTag);

    function saveOrRemoveTag(savedTags) {

        var noSavedTags = savedTags.length == 0;
        if (noSavedTags) { checkedSave(); return; }

        tagAlreadyExists() ? removeTag(tag, associatedTicker) : checkedSave();

        // the 3 lines above are really the entire function
        // everything below is just helper functions

        function checkedSave() {
            total < 3 ? saveTag(tag, associatedTicker)
                      : displayAlert('failure', 'Only 3 tags can be monitored at a time.');
        }

        function tagAlreadyExists() {
            var existingTermIds = savedTags.map(function(t) { return t.term_id });
            return existingTermIds.indexOf(tag.term_id) > -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I love Ternary statements :D wasn't thinking about them in this case, but this is very clean.

Comment: Glad you like it.  You could go even further and have just one big ternary, eliminating all `if`s: `noSavedTags ? checkedSave() : tagAlreadyExists() ? removeTag(tag, associatedTicker) : checkedSave();`  With proper formatting and aligment it can be very readable.

Comment: This is super helpful too `var noSavedTags = data.length == 0;` I do length checks a lot in my app, this is short and more straight forward.

Comment: Dang didn't know you could chain Ternary's like that, so the return of the first check will feed into the next?

Comment: Yeah, I try to push "naming every concept" as far as I can in my own code.  It forces you to separate meaning and implementation, and allows you to _read meaning_, while ignoring implementation, when you return to your code.  It's probably the single best method for making your code readable.

Comment: It's actually just that the "false" branch of the first ternary is _itself_ another ternary.  Which is perfectly fine, because a ternary requires two expressions, and since a ternary is itself an expression, it's perfectly legal.  I think it's important if you use this method that each "piece" is just a single well-named function call or variable.  Otherwise it's just being fancy without being readable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think of two techniques for optimizing:

1. You can save *one* `if`, just joining together the two existing `saveTag` calls
2. You can avoid iterating the array *twice*, just by storing the found index and passing it as a parameter to the `removeTag` method.

Like this:

```
    function processTag(total, tag, associatedTicker) {
    var foundFlag = false;

    TagFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags').then(function(data) {
    console.log('onlyTags data',data);

        // Are there are selected Tags:
        // Search for tag in tagFactory
        var tagIndex=searchTagInArray(data, tag);

        // If found, remove tag:
        if (tagIndex>=0) {
            removeTag(tag, associatedTicker, tagIndex);
        }
        else {
            // Save the tag if not found or there are not selected tags:
            if (data.length==0 || total < 3) {
                saveTag(tag, associatedTicker);
            }
            // 3 are already selected, display alert:
            else {
                displayAlert('failure', 'Only 3 tags can be monitored at a time.');
            }
        }
    });
}

function searchTagInArray(data, tag){
    var foundIndex=-1;
    for (var i=0; foundIndex<0 && i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].term_id === tag.term_id) {
            foundIndex = true;
        }
    }
    return foundIndex;
}
```

And if you can replace the array for a *HashMap*, you can save the whole `searchTagInArray` method:

(Assuming `retrieveTickerTags` returns `data` as a HashMap of tags indexed by `term_id`: `data={term0: tag0, term1: tag1, term2: tag2...}`)

```
function processTag(total, tag, associatedTicker) {
    TagFactory.retrieveTickerTags('onlyTags').then(function(data) {
        console.log('onlyTags data',data);

        // Are there selected Tags:
        // Search for tag in tagFactory
        var oldTag=data[tag.term_id];

        // If found, remove tag:
        if (oldTag) {
            removeTag(tag, associatedTicker);
        }
        else {
            // Save the tag if not found or there are not selected tags:
            if (isEmpty(data) || total < 3) {
                saveTag(tag, associatedTicker);
            }
            // 3 are already selected, display alert:
            else {
                displayAlert('failure', 'Only 3 tags can be monitored at a time.');
            }
        }
    });
}

function isEmpty(data)
{
    for (field in data)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! I actually am writing all the frontend code, so I can use a `Hashmap` if it would make things easier... I'm actually googling it now hehe

Comment: If you use a HashMap, it will be much better.

Comment: Could you post a HashMap example as well?

Comment: I've added the HashMap alternative to my post.